# sort with subquery not working in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

In Controller I have

```
        $this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => array(
                'User.id', 'User.username', 'User.fullname', 'User.role', 'User.user_remarks',
                '( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(B.profit), 0) FROM businesses B WHERE B.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(J.cost, 0)*IFNULL(J.duration, 0)), 0) FROM jobs J WHERE J.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(FI.income), 0) FROM fixed_incomes FI WHERE FI.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(OI.income), 0) FROM other_incomes OI WHERE OI.user_id = User.id ) AS total_income',
                '( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(FE.expense), 0) FROM fixed_expenses FE WHERE FE.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(E.cost), 0) FROM expenses E WHERE E.user_id = USER.id ) AS total_expense',
            ),
            'conditions' => $conditions,
        );

        $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate('User'));
```

In View I have

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('total_income',__("Income (This month)")); ?>
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('total_expense',__("Spending (This month)")); ?>
```

Sorting link is clickable and page refreshes. But sort is not working. Order By virtual column name not appended to query automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try declaring them as virtual fields?

as per:

> http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-in-sql-queries

try:

```
$this->virtualFields['total_expense'] = 0;
$this->virtualFields['total_income'] = 0;
$this->paginate = array(
            'fields' => array(
                'User.id', 'User.username', 'User.fullname', 'User.role', 'User.user_remarks',
                '( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(B.profit), 0) FROM businesses B WHERE B.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(J.cost, 0)*IFNULL(J.duration, 0)), 0) FROM jobs J WHERE J.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(FI.income), 0) FROM fixed_incomes FI WHERE FI.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(OI.income), 0) FROM other_incomes OI WHERE OI.user_id = User.id ) AS User__total_income',
                '( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(FE.expense), 0) FROM fixed_expenses FE WHERE FE.user_id = User.id ) +
 ( SELECT IFNULL(SUM(E.cost), 0) FROM expenses E WHERE E.user_id = USER.id ) AS User__total_expense',
            ),
            'conditions' => $conditions,
        );

        $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate('User'));
```